# using angularjs to read json file, but its not happening

Tags: json, angularjs

This is not working for reading and inserting data, I have data.json in js folder

```
<ion-content>
  <div ng-controller="jsonCtrl" ng-repeat="d in data">
    <h2>{{d[0].name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{d[0].shortname}}</h2>
    <h2>{{d[0].reknown}}</h2>
    <p>{{d[0].bio}}</p>

      <h2>Total Data {{ getTotalData() }}</h2>

      <label>Name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Name">

      <label>Short name</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Shortname">

      <label>Reknown</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Reknown">

      <label>Bio</label>
      <input type="text" ng-model="Bio">

      <button ng-click="addData()">Add</button>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('starter', ['ionic'])

.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
    // Hide the accessory bar by default 
    // (remove this to show the accessory bar above the keyboard for form inputs)
    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(true);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
    }
  });
})
```

My controller looks like this:

```
.controller('jsonCtrl', function($scope, $http) {

  $http.get('data.json').success(function(res) {
    $scope.data = res;
    console.log($scope.data);
  });

  $scope.addData = function() {
    $scope.data.push({
      name: $scope.Name,
      shortname: $scope.Shortname,
      reknown: $scope.Reknown,
      bio: $scope.Bio
    });
  }

  $scope.getTotalData = function() {
    return $scope.data.length;
  }
});
```

**EDIT**:

Example of `data.json`:

```
{ "speakers" : [
  { 
    "name":"Mr Bellingham",
    "shortname":"Barot_Bellingham",
    "reknown":"Royal Academy of Painting and Sculpture",
    "bio":"Barot has just finished his final year at The Royal Academy"
  },
  // etc...
]}
```

Comment: sorry if code formatting is inappropriate. I added controller just after run like this: 
 
.controller('jsonCtrl', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('data.json').success(function (res){
        $scope.data = res;
        console.log($scope.data);
    });

    $scope.addData = function(){
        $scope.data.push({ name:$scope.Name, shortname:$scope.Shortname, reknown:$scope.Reknown ,bio:$scope.Bio });
    }
    
    $scope.getTotalData= function(){
        return $scope.data.length;    
    }
    
});

Comment: @New Dev Did this code worked on your application?? Actually I tried this already but didn't find working. There is only minute change right in this code, like  .controller('jsonCtrl', ['$scope','$http', function($scope,$http){  to    .controller('jsonCtrl', function($scope,$http){

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*EDIT: I edited the answer because there seem to be more issues in the OP's code*

First, you shouldn't place `ng-repeat` and `ng-controller` on the same element. `ng-repeat` has a higher priority, so, what happens is that you have a controller for each iteration of the `ng-repeat`.

Instead, place `ng-controller` on the parent element:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data">      
    etc ...

  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Second, your `$scope.data` is an array of objects, so `{{d[0].name}}` seems incorrect - what is the need for `[0]`? - `d` already points to each item:

```
<ion-content ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data">      
    <h2>{{d.name}}</h2>
    <h2>{{d.shortname}}</h2>
    <h2>{{d.reknown}}</h2>
    <p>{{d.bio}}</p>
  </div>
</ion-content>
```

Third, the new item should be outside of the `ng-repeat` - you don't intend to repeat it, right?

```
<ion-content ng-controller="jsonCtrl">
  <div ng-repeat="d in data">      
    <h2>{{d.name}}</h2>
    ... etc
  </div>

  <label>Name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="Name">

  <label>Short name</label>
  <input type="text" ng-model="newItem.shortname">

  ... etc

  <button ng-click="addData()">Add</button>    

</ion-content>
```

Lastly, I'd strongly encourage you to always use bind `ng-model` to some object's property (or, always use dot `.`) - instead of directly to a scope property. This has to do with scope's prototypical inheritance - without the dot (`.`), you would be writing into the property of a child scope, if some directive (e.g. `ng-if`) created one. It's also easier to reset it.

```
$scope.newItem = {};
$scope.addData = function(){
  $scope.data.push($scope.newItem);
  $scope.newItem = {};
}
```

```
<label>Name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="newItem.name">

<label>Short name</label>
<input type="text" ng-model="newItem.shortname">

... etc
```

Comment: @NiteshDhakal, you accepted this answer - did you get it to work?

Comment: Nope it didnt work, may be something wrong in my js. can you help plz

Comment: That didnt worked actually. You asked for the json file format i commented as answer below.

Comment: @NiteshDhakal What exactly does "didn't work" mean? And please remove the answer below - answers are just that - answers, not edits or comments. You can edit the original question instead

Comment: @NiteshDhakal, ok, based on your data, you seem to be iterating over `$scope.data.speakers`, so change to `ng-repeat="d in data.speakers"`

Comment: but it still not doing, I guess im irritating you. But I dont know whats happening,

Comment: Yeah sir, Thanks a lot! It worked and I have one Question, What should we do to get specific data from json array?? Regards